# How do I allow trains going in the same direction to not stop at the signals?

Tags: openttd

I currently have an intersection of trains. 4 go parallel and 1 perpendicular. I would like to let the 4 parallel trains all go if they approach the intersection at the same time. However, they all stop until one train gets through. I have to admit I'm not so great at signals, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Here's the layout:

[image]

Comment: If the lines have high activity, and you have realistic acceleration enabled, it might be a good idea to use bridges for the crossing instead of having to use signals, which are blocking

Comment: also you might want to consider a [RoRo station](http://wiki.openttd.org/Building_railway_stations)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the perfect opportunity for [path signals](http://wiki.openttd.org/Signal#Path_Signals). They show the train which routes are available and therefore the parallel trains will only have to stop when the perpendicular path is taken.